# I have ngOauth access_token now what?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, oauth, ionic-framework

So I am trying to add a login with facebook / twitter option to my mobile app. I have installed ngcordova oauth plugin and everything is working. User clicks login, it takes them to FB, they accept the permissions, takes them back to the app, and I have the access_token object. Perfect. Except what do I do with it now? Now that I have the token I should be able to request the specific info I need (email / name) How is this done? Do I have to install the ios & android facebook sdk and the ios & twitter sdk? Is this built into ionic? can I simply use web calls? I am very confused on how I actually get user email / whatever other info I requested in the access_token after I retrieve permission. Here is my code currently

```
$scope.facebookLogin = function() {
    $cordovaOauth.facebook("xxxxxxxxxxxxx", ["email"]).then(function(result) {
        // results
        console.log("Success");
        console.log(result);
    }, function(error) {
        // error
        console.log("Failure");
        console.log(error);
    });
}
```

I am getting in the success block, but now I need to know what to do with the access_token to actually get values.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution that I found that actually works for future persons

```
    $accessToken = result.access_token;
    $http.get("https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/me", { params: { access_token: $accessToken, format: "json" }}).then(function(result) {
        //this is where the user data is stored
        var user_data = result.data;
        console.log(user_data);
    }, function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
```